# If a number is a Prime Number?

Tags: python

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
            return True
```

I'd like to know why this code omits two when saying if a number isPrime and how do I fix it if I should make the value of n be 2.

Answer (score 0):

range(2,2) is empty.

you can see it by doing

`for i in range(2,2):
    print(i)`

Answer (score 0):

It omits 2 because of the `range` function:

```
print(list(range(2,2)))
[]
```

In your code, if you want to include n, you should use `range(2,n+1)`

for this specific issue, you could do something like:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    elif n == 2:
        return False
    else:
        prime = True
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n%i == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        return prime

print(isPrime(6))
```

The `elif` catches the special case where `n == 2`. Additionally, I inserted an extra variable which is set to `False` when the modulo becomes `0` (thus, the variable is **not** a prime number)

The `break` makes sure that the check is stopped once a remainder becomes `0`, and it is returned whether your variable is prime or not.

I checked it, and got to the following results:

```
False
```

for input = `6`

and

```
True
```

for input = `11`

Comment: Hey, thanks. But I don't want I to go to n. So should I say after the for I in range (2,n+1), for i <n

Comment: @ÎtzBellaEnnuh the `for i in range(2,n)` will **not** use n in it's computations, so printing `i` for `i in range(2,10)` will print number going from 2 (included) up to 10 (excluded). If you don't want to include `n`, then `range(2,n)` is fine indeed, but this will yield issues for `n == 2`. Maybe `elif n == 2` could solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Im new to python. About two days lol.
But i think i can see what the problem is.
The range(a, b) function counts to the length "b-a" 
because thats what a range is(highest - smallest)
So when you're using the range() function write it out this way:

```
def isPrime(n):
if n == 1: 
    return False 
else: 
    for i in range(1,n): 
        if n%i == 0: 
            return False 
        return True

print(isPrime(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

It omits 2 because `range(2,2)` is empty, like the other answers have stated. However, for n=2 you WANT the range to be empty, because you never want to include 1 (every positive integer is divisible by 1), and 2 is divisible by 2. In general, you want to use `range(2, n)` because n is divisible by n.

Another problem here is that you return `True` within the for loop; this means that on the first pass through the loop for n≥3, if n is odd the function will return `True`. The solution to this is just to knock the `return True` statement back a level of indentation. That way, if the range is empty, or only after checking if `n` is divisible by every number from 2 to n-1 inclusive, you return `True`. It should look something like this:

```
def isPrime(n):
if n == 1:
    return False
else:
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

"The simplest primality test is trial division: Given an input number n, check whether any prime integer m from 2 to √n evenly divides n (the division leaves no remainder). If n is divisible by any m then n is composite, otherwise it is prime."

- [Wikipedia article on primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), Look at the simple test to understand why this works.

It looks like you keep dividing numbers to see if any number up to that number divides it. You will realize that for a given n, the largest number that can divide n is some m, such that 2 * m = n. So firstly, indexing all the way up to n is checking each case twice. Example:

```
8 % 1 == 8? 
8 % 2 == 0? -> 8 / 2 = 4
8 % 3 == 0?
8 % 4 == 0? -> 8 / 4 = 2
8 % 5 == 0?
8 % 6 == 0?
8 % 7 == 0?
```

To mitigate these duplicate checks: You square i, and only check divisors (i) no greater √n. In this case, `n=8`, We stop at `i = 3`, because then we just swap the divisors order, and check the same cases over again.

Also note: We will start our loop at n = 5, because we check the base cases n = 1, 2 or 3? and we know 4 is not prime:

Output:

```
1 is not prime
2 is prime
3 is prime
4 is not prime
5 is prime
6 is not prime
7 is prime
8 is not prime
9 is not prime
```

Code:

```
# Via Trivial division
def isPrime(n):

    # False by definition
    if n <= 1:
        return False

    # Consider 2 and 3 base cases
    # for THIS method of detecting
    # prime numbers (trivial division)
    elif n <= 3:
        return True

    # Check that 2 or 3 divides n
    elif n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False

    i = 5

    while (i * i) <= n:

        if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2):
            return False
        i = i + 6

    return True

#--------------------------------------

j = 1
while j < 10:
    if (isPrime(j)):
        print(str(j) + " is prime")

    else:
        print(str(j) + " is not prime")

    j = j + 1
```